# Expandable List View using fragments and tab layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview, android-tablayout, expandablelistadapter

Hey guys so basically im trying to create an expandable list view in one of the tabs of my app (say the "active" tab) so it is made of fragments of course so i have tried this code to make the expandable list view work with fragments, it is showing the header items but only the first header item when clicked is expandable the second and third are not responding and the child of the first header item are also not responding on click, Could someone please help me out with this,

Fragment layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff8400" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Frag1 Java class:

```
package com.example.home.designbosmrohit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;




    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1_layout, container, false);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        return view;
    }
    private void prepareListData()
    {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
        top250.add("The Dark Knight");
        top250.add("12 Angry Men");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }



}
```

and the output image:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEiqC.png)

the list items are not clickable and im not able to expand the "Now showing" and "Coming Soon" header, could someone please help me out with this

Comment: I tried your code from github and found that there is another ExpandableListView in activity_main.xml that is of same id. After removed it, child click works normally.

Comment: thank you so much bro it is working as desired :D

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: No mate, this is also not working unfortunately, i replaced the getApplicationContext as it was not working so i  tried to log that code which you had put there in the onCreateView Method and its still not working, the github link for the project https://github.com/rohit901/DesignBosmRohit